# How to set global tags in Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: pulumi

In a stack specific settings file (i.e. `Pulumi.dev.yaml`), if location is set (i.e. `azure-native:location`) then resource group location is set automatically and location for resources is derived from resource group location. Now I am trying to apply common tag for all resources i.e. `CreatedBy: Pulumi`. **Is there any way to set common/global tags, similar to `azure-native:location`** in settings file (`Pulumi.dev.yaml`) ?

Expected: both location and tags will be set from `Pulumi.dev.yaml`

```yaml
config:
  azure-native:location: japaneast
  azure-native:tags:
    CreatedBy: Pulumi
```

```cs
var mainRgArgs = config.RequireObject<JsonElement>(KEY_RESOURCE_GROUP_ARGS);
var mainRgName = mainRgArgs.GetProperty(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME).GetString()!;

var mainRg = new ResourceGroup(RESOURCE_GROUP_MAIN, new ResourceGroupArgs
{
    ResourceGroupName = mainRgName
    //Location = 
    //Tags = 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to set the tags automatically, because tags aren't a required API property.

The reason `location` is a provider argument is because every resource requires a location when it's created. That isn't true for tags.

However, it is possible to automatically add tags to resources that are taggable (which isn't all resources) using a [transformation](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/#transformations)

Transformations allow you to inject properties into every resource, regardless of whether you've set that value on your resource explicitly. You will however have to set a list of taggable resources, because not every Azure resource is taggable.

A function which will register tags on resources will look something like this:

```
export function registerAutoTags(autoTags: Record<string, string>): void {
    pulumi.runtime.registerStackTransformation((args) => {
        if (isTaggable(args.type)) {
            args.props["tags"] = { ...args.props["tags"], ...autoTags };
            return { props: args.props, opts: args.opts };
        }
        return undefined;
    });
}
```

and then you can use those tags by calling the function:

```
registerAutoTags({
    "user:Project": pulumi.getProject(),
    "user:Stack": pulumi.getStack(),
    "user:Cost Center": config.require("costCenter"),
});
```

There's more information on this (albeit for AWS, not Azure) [here](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/automatically-enforcing-aws-resource-tagging-policies/). You can find a list of Azure resources that are support tags [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support)

Comment: one question, after applying transformation, what will happen if tags are applied at resource level? if tag "X" is applied by transformations and Tags "Y" & "Z" are applied when resource is created, tags will be merged -> resource will have all 3 tags "X, Y, Z"

Comment: yes, all 3 tags will be added.

Comment: I was able to add common tags using transformations: [Applying Common Tags using Transformations](https://hovermind.com/pulumi/resource-tag#applying-common-tags-using-transformations)